# Local store video webRTC

Tags: html, webrtc, video-capture

I used the the information from the link ([here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/)) and got the following code, which helps me to record a video with my webcam. The code allows me to record a video and makes it available to download. However, I want to save the recorded video automatically to a local folder. How can I do that?

```
<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
    <section class="experiment">
        <div class="inner">
            <button style="float: right;" id="fit-to-screen">Fit to Screen!</button>
            <label for="canvas-width-input">Canvas Width</label>
            <input type="text" id="canvas-width-input" value="320">
            <br />
            <label for="canvas-height-input">Canvas Height</label>
            <input type="text" id="canvas-height-input" value="240">
            <br />
            <div>
                <button id="record-video">Record</button>
                <button id="pause-resume-video" disabled>Pause</button>
                <button id="stop-recording-video" disabled>Stop</button>
                <hr>
                <h2 id="video-url-preview"></h2>
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="record-screen" style="width:auto;">
                <label for="record-screen">Record Screen</label>
                <br>
                <video id="video" autoplay loop controls muted></video>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <script>
        (function() {
            var params = {},
                r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g;

            function d(s) {
                return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
            }

            var match, search = window.location.search;
            while (match = r.exec(search.substring(1)))
                params[d(match[1])] = d(match[2]);

            window.params = params;
        })();
    </script>

    <script>
    function getByID(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    var recordVideo = getByID('record-video'),
        pauseResumeVideo = getByID('pause-resume-video'),
        stopRecordingVideo = getByID('stop-recording-video');

    var canvasWidth_input = getByID('canvas-width-input'),
        canvasHeight_input = getByID('canvas-height-input');

    if(params.canvas_width) {
        canvasWidth_input.value = params.canvas_width;
    }

    if(params.canvas_height) {
        canvasHeight_input.value = params.canvas_height;
    }

    var video = getByID('video');

    var videoConstraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            mandatory: {},
            optional: []
        }
    };

    </script>

    <script>
    var screen_constraints;
    function isCaptureScreen(callback) {
        if (document.getElementById('record-screen').checked) {
            document.getElementById('fit-to-screen').onclick();

            getScreenId(function (error, sourceId, _screen_constraints) {
                if(error === 'not-installed') {
                    window.open('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capturing/ajhifddimkapgcifgcodmmfdlknahffk');                        
                }

                if(error === 'permission-denied') {
                    alert('Screen capturing permission is denied.');
                }

                if(error === 'installed-disabled') {
                    alert('Please enable chrome screen capturing extension.');
                }

                if(_screen_constraints) {
                    screen_constraints = _screen_constraints.video;
                    videoConstraints = _screen_constraints;
                }
                else {
                    videoConstraints = screen_constraints;
                }

                callback();
            });
        }
        else {
            callback();
        }
    }

    recordVideo.onclick = function() {
        isCaptureScreen(function() {
            recordVideoOrGIF(true);
        });
    };


    function recordVideoOrGIF(isRecordVideo) {
        navigator.getUserMedia(videoConstraints, function(stream) {
            video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
                video.width = canvasWidth_input.value || 320;
                video.height = canvasHeight_input.value || 240;

                var options = {
                    type: isRecordVideo ? 'video' : 'gif',
                    video: video,
                    canvas: {
                        width: canvasWidth_input.value,
                        height: canvasHeight_input.value
                    },
                    disableLogs: params.disableLogs || false,
                    recorderType: null // to let RecordRTC choose relevant types itself
                };

                recorder = window.RecordRTC(stream, options);
                recorder.startRecording();

                video.onloadedmetadata = false;
            };
            video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }, function() {
            if (document.getElementById('record-screen').checked) {
                if (location.protocol === 'http:')
                    alert('<https> is mandatory to capture screen.');
                else
                    alert('Multi-capturing of screen is not allowed. Capturing process is denied. Are you enabled flag: "Enable screen capture support in getUserMedia"?');
            } else
                alert('Webcam access is denied.');
        });

        window.isAudio = false;

        if (isRecordVideo) {
            recordVideo.disabled = true;
            stopRecordingVideo.disabled = false;
            pauseResumeVideo.disabled = false;
        }
    }


    stopRecordingVideo.onclick = function() {
        this.disabled = true;
        recordVideo.disabled = false;

        if (recorder)
            recorder.stopRecording(function(url) {
                video.src = url;
                video.play();

                document.getElementById('video-url-preview').innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">Recorded Video URL</a>';
            });
    };


    </script>

    <script>
    document.getElementById('fit-to-screen').onclick = function() {
        this.disabled = true;

        video.width = canvasWidth_input.value = innerWidth;
        video.height = canvasHeight_input.value = innerHeight;
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: you want the video to be recorded within your browser itself? no need of server?

Comment: I forgot to mention that detail, I am running XAMPP for my local server and codeigniter as my framework...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the `recorder.getBlob()` method to get the actual blob of the video file, then send it to your server which will then save it to a file :

### javascript:

```
stopRecordingVideo.onclick = function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    recordVideo.disabled = false;

    if (recorder)
        recorder.stopRecording(function(url) {
            video.src = url;
            video.play();
            var recordedBlob = recorder.getBlob();
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("videofile", recordedBlob);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "savevideofile.php");
            xhr.send(formData);
            document.getElementById('video-url-preview').innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '>Recorded Video URL</a>';
        });
};
```

### savevideofile.php:

```
<?php
if($_FILES['videofile']){
    $my_file = $_FILES['videofile'];
    $my_blob = file_get_contents($my_file['tmp_name']);
    file_put_contents('/path/to/your/file.webm', $my_blob);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where should the savevideofile.php be? In the same folder as my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes or wherever you want but specify the good path in the ajax call (`xhr.open("POST", "/the/path/to/your.php");`)

Comment: it gives me the following error
POST http://localhost/Test/application/views/savevideofile.php
403 Forbidden

Comment: Check that you have write access to your folder (might be settable in the properties but I'm not on windows so can't check rn)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code of the web page you linked, the 'url' from your callback for **stopRecording** should be a downloadable URL.

All you'd have to do would be to take that URL and use it in an anchor with [HTML5 *download* attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute), like so:

```
recorder.stopRecording(function(url) {
            video.src = url;
            video.play();

            document.getElementById('video-url-preview').innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank" download="myVideo.mp4">Recorded Video URL</a>';
        });
```

Comment: But then it won't "save the recorded video automatically to a local folder." but provide a prompt where the user will be able to save where he wants.

Comment: + The file provided by RecordRTC is encoded with [vp8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP8) codec, which should be encapsulated in a `.webm` file.

Comment: loaded JS code can't "automatically save to a local file" at least ignoring indexdb/etc.  To save to a user-accessible file requires the user to ok it

Comment: Yes. You always need user conffirmation at the time being. As far as I know at least. I don't even see a way to do it with ChromeOS.