# Save / export webm videos to app directory from JavaScript in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, video, shiny, webm

I have integrated a webcam video capture into a Shiny app using RecordRTC and JavaScript. That works great and I can access and store my videos in a JavaScript variable named "video.blob". However, I struggle with exporting that file into my app's shiny directory upon pressing a "btn-save-recording" button.

I have tried to pass the blob to shiny as suggested here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html

```
Shiny.setInputValue("videoObject", video.blob)
```

I also tried passing it to shiny as part of a form:

```
var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('video', video.blob);
    Shiny.setInputValue("videoObject", formData)
```

However, I have so far neither been able to access the videoObject in Shiny nor to save it to the app directory.

I also tried coding a solution in PHP as suggested here https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/671/how-to-record-a-video-with-audio-in-the-browser-with-javascript-webrtc and here [Local store video webRTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374084/local-store-video-webrtc). However, executing the PHP script returns a "400 Bad Request Error". I never used PHP before, so there is a good chance I did something wrong or PHP doesn't work on a Shiny server in the first place.

I would greatly appreciate any information on

- How to save a webm video to my app directory from JavaScript on Shiny
- How to pass a webm video from JavaScript to Shiny such that I can work with it with libraries such as opencv, imager, or av.
- In case there is no easy way to accomplish the above I would appreciate some advice on what type of other server I should launch that would be able to receive my webm videos sent from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer:

**In JavaScript**

1. Convert the video blob into a base 64 encoded string using the URL.getDataURL() function (based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).

Code:

```
recorder.getDataURL(function(dataURL) {
        video.data = dataURL;
    });
```

2. Pass that data to the Shiny.onInputChange variable that Shiny initializes in JavaScript.

Code:

```
var formData = {id:123, data: video.data}
Shiny.onInputChange("videoobject", formData)
```

**In R / Shiny**

1. Remove the *data:*/*;base64,* prefix that JavaScript adds.
2. Convert from base_64 back to binary.
3. Store binary file on server.

Code:

```
observeEvent(input$videoobject,{
     data <- input$videoobject$data
     writeBin(jsonlite::base64_dec(substr(data,24,nchar(data))), "www/test_video.webm")
    })
```